# F# Interface with static member

Tags: interface, f#

How to define a static member in an Interface?
Why it is not possible?

I want to force a F# type (class) to have a static method to create an instance of itself from a string (JSON parsing). 
I want this Interface example:

```ml
[<Interface>]
type public ILikeJson<'T> =
    abstract member ToJson: unit -> string         // OK
    static abstract member FromJson: string -> 'T  // <-- "static" is not valid here !
```

Alternatively a constructor from a string can do the work but a static method sounds better because it will have an appropriate name and I don't know how to define a constructor in the Interface too.

Comment: [As of 8/9/2022](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/13119), F# does support [interfaces with static abstract members (RFC FS-1124)](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/FSharp-7.0/FS-1124-interfaces-with-static-abstract-members.md). For example, this will compile in `dotnet fsi`: `type I = static abstract i: unit -> string;; type A = A interface I with static member i () = "lofa";;` (albeit, I couldn't figure out how to use it as `A.i()` will blow up... I also couldn't find any docs other than the linked RFC itself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The present CLR specification states that interfaces are only implemented for object *instances* and do not apply for the types themselves.

C# 8 has a proposal for defining static interface members, but it is required to provide an implementation for the static methods within the interface definition itself. So you won't be able to implement a `FromJson` method per class.

If you try this in F#, you'll get:

> FS0868: Interfaces cannot contain definitions of concrete members. You may need to define a constructor on your type to indicate that the type is a class.

One solution to this problem is to use [static type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters). They allow you to look up the existence of a method on a type.

```
let inline create< ^T when ^T : (static member FromJson: string -> ^T)> json = 
     (^T : (static member FromJson: string -> ^T) (json))
```

This supports any type which has a static method `FromJson` with the `string -> T` signature.

```
type Number(num: double) =
    member _.Value = num
    static member FromJson (json) = new Number(Double.Parse(json))
```

and to use:

```
create<Number> "1.5" //creates a Number(1.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, I also went trought the "inline" keyword trying to find a different solution, interesting. My goal was to force a bunch of classes/types to expose the same "ToJson" and static "FromJson" methods. Kind of "forced naming convention". Wrong use of Interface, I finished to just add these methods drectly to the classes/types, any other solution seems to be too cumbersome (also because the FromJson will be used from C#). Useful example anyway, thanks.

Comment: A common pattern is to implement a `Parse` method which takes in a json string, which modifies the class' fields. This is similar to the approach taken by `ISerializable`.

Comment: I don't know the higher purpose of this - but to serialize/deserialize types in specific ways, I've always implemented a custom data contract resolver.

Comment: The higher purpose is actaully a problem with JSON serialization.  Both Newtonsoft and JIL fail to serialize the type "OpenOrder" (https://alex75.visualstudio.com/_git/Cryptocurrencies?path=%2FAlex75.Cryptocurrencies%2Fmodels%2FOrders.fs) and I don't want to add a parameterles contructor (required by JIL).

Comment: Also JsonContructor attribute in a child element constructor (CurrencyPair type) does not work and in general I don't  want to pollute a type with too many attributes. Using a custom Serializer class that manage parsing a string from/to JSON for that types was another approach I have think about. For now the two specific methods in the instance of the class (OpenOrder) will solve my problem. Thanks for the tips.